# Keyboard and Mouse not working in Blender

Tags: animation, scripting, interface, import

I recently opened the first build of 2.8 for Blender and for some reason none of the keyboard keys work, nor the mouse. I can click all the side menus and different buttons but hitting hotkeys does nothing. So I installed Candidate 3 thinking I just needed the new one. Same issue, I did a factory reset in the preferences, I tried uninstalling and reinstalling. I tried using the repair option in the Setup Wizard. Nothing has worked, I can open Blender files and what not but literally no keystrokes register.

If I go into preferences page, when adding a Add-on it says Traceback error. I also go into the Keymap tab thinking maybe I hit something but the tab is completely empty and I can't figure what to do to fix this.[image]

If anyone knows the issue, please help because I use Blender to practice to land an Animation job one day and if I can't use it I can't progress.

Error Messages: sorry for the home screen one I barely missed it.[image]
[image]

Ran the debug_log This is a brief summary because it is far too long.

location: :-1

location: :-1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils__init__.py", line 187, in register_module_call
    register()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\startup\bl_operators__init__.py", line 70, in register
    register_class(cls)
ValueError: register_class(...): already registered as a subclass

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy__init__.py", line 81, in 
    main()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy__init__.py", line 78, in main
    utils.load_scripts()
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils__init__.py", line 260, in load_scripts
    test_register(mod)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils__init__.py", line 229, in test_register
    register_module_call(mod)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\modules\bpy\utils__init__.py", line 189, in register_module_call
    import traceback

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\python\lib\traceback.py", line 5, in 
    import linecache

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\python\lib\linecache.py", line 11, in 
    import tokenize

File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\python\lib\tokenize.py", line 33, in 
    import re
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\python\lib\re.py", line 122, in 
    import enum
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\python\lib\enum.py", line 2, in 
    from types import MappingProxyType, DynamicClassAttribute
ImportError: cannot import name 'MappingProxyType' from 'types' (C:\Users\ahuls\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.80\scripts\addons\types.py)

location: :-1

location: :-1
WARN (wm.keymap): K:\BlenderGit\blender\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_keymap.c:467 WM_keymap_poll: empty keymap 'Grease Pencil'

WARN (wm.keymap): K:\BlenderGit\blender\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_keymap.c:467 WM_keymap_poll: empty keymap 'Grease Pencil Stroke Edit Mode'

WARN (wm.keymap): K:\BlenderGit\blender\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_keymap.c:467 WM_keymap_poll: empty keymap 'Grease Pencil Stroke Paint Mode'

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the error messages you are seeing. Please make sure that you're using current graphics driver and that your system fulfills the minimum requirements for Blender 2.8 https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/

Comment: I am updated in both driver and I meet the system requirements, I know this because Blender Beta was working fine prior to it randomly not working. I am still confused why the Keymap tab is empty.

Comment: Did you save your preferences after resetting the factory settings? Like described here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146978/blender-2-8-keeps-crashing-while-rendering/147191#147191

Comment: yes I do save preferences after factory reset. For some reason the Keymap Tab stays empty

Comment: Can you try to download the archive version (.zip) of Blender 2.8 and check if that works properly? https://www.blender.org/download/ perhaps something went wrong during install if you had 2.79 previously installed (or in general).

Comment: I can understand what your saying. However, I have Blender 2.8 Beta. I created an animation rendered images and what not. It just suddenly stopped working one day. I am currently attempting to download the official 2.8 Release and will give an update

Comment: If the problem persists, please run `blender_debug_log.cmd` from the install directory and upload the log file somewhere (or add it to your question if it isn't too long).

Comment: I ran the debug and I have added some of the information in the post, the file itself was far too long to post the whole thing.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the first error in the file. Is that the first error?

Comment: yes, I copied and pasted the very beginning, it continues on with more warn lines.

Comment: Can you go to install directory of Blender, type `cmd` in the address bar, press enter. Then type `.\blender.exe --factory-startup`. Does it make any difference? It looks there are problems with all python add-ons and their registration.

Comment: Just to clarify, do I go into Blender's preferences. Then Addons, type in CMD? because I tried that and I feel like I did the wrong thing because nothing happened

Comment: No open the Windows Explorer and navigate to the directory where you have installed Blender (it's likely `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender`). Then click into the field where it displays the path and type `cmd`, then press enter. It should open a command line window in that directory.

Comment: @Alexander You need a clean installation, but I don't know if they bother you here about an answer about it since it's about configurations and programming not related to 3D modeling, and I don't really want to be arguing that a question is a question and if you have answer should not be limited to being left unanswered just because it is co-related to the subject and not the subject

Comment: @BlenderBlackened We're trying to diagnose the problem. Reinstalling may or may not help depending on what the cause is, which btw I already suggested to rule out a broken installation. Not sure where you get the impression that we're not trying to help?

Comment: @Alexander DELETE manually this folder 1-. C:\Users\Your_USER_ \AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation 2-. DELETE manually this folder: C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation, clean tour reg_key with CCleaner, and clean all temporal files with ccleaner, restart your PC, and reinstall blender 2.8, NOTE: you will lose all the addons that you have in previous versions of blender, if you want to repair any you must do it before deleting the folder that is in AppData \ Roaming \ Blender Foundation, please feed me if your clean installation was successful

Comment: preferably remove the installer that I use, both from your folder and from the recycling basket, and download a new one, try using an installer that indicates BLENDER RELEASE

Comment: If this does not solve your problem go directly to me to teach you how to compile blender in 10 minutes

Comment: I would advise against installing CCleaner or editing the registry.

Comment: Also **do not** delete Blender from Program Files if you have used an installer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97205/discussion-between-blender-blackened-and-rjg).

Comment: I want to thank you rjg for sticking with me this whole time and trying to help I really appreciate it. Also, thank you Blender Blackened for also trying to help. I have been away for a couple days so I am barely seeing this. I do not have enough reputation to go into chat so I apologize for that.